# Template inheritance and a base member variable

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, base-class

I get a weird error when trying to use template inheritance.
This is my code:

```
template <class T> class A {
public:
    int a {2};
    A(){};
};

template <class T> class B : public A<T> {
    public:
    B(): A<T>() {};
    void test(){    std::cout << "testing... " << a << std::endl;   };
};
```

And this is the error:

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'a'; did you mean 'std::uniform_int_distribution<long>::a'?
    void test(){    std::cout << "testing... " << a << std::endl;   }
```

And in case it could affect something I use these flags:

```
-Wall -g -std=c++11
```

I really don't know what is wrong since the same code as pure classes without templating works fine.

Comment: `void test(){    std::cout << "testing... " << A<T>::a << std::endl;   };`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I really don't know what is wrong since the same code as pure classes without templating works fine.

This is because the base class (class template `A`) is not a nondependent base class, its type can't be determined without knowing the template arguments. And `a` is a nondependent name. Nondependent names are not looked up in dependent base classes.

To correct the code, you could make the name `a` dependent, dependent names can be looked up only at the time of instantiation, at that time the exact base specialization must be explored and will be known.

You could

```
void test() { std::cout << "testing... " << this->a << std::endl; };
```

or

```
void test() { std::cout << "testing... " << A<T>::a << std::endl; };
```

or

```
void test() { 
    using A<T>::a;
    std::cout << "testing... " << a << std::endl; 
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It makes sense now:)